# Why won't my grayscale function affect the entire canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm a new programmer, and I've been trying to create a grayscale function through JS for practice.

My code:

```
<canvas width='400' height='400'></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        grayscale();
    }
    image.src = 'images/fry.jpg';

    function grayscale () {
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var data = imageData.data;
        var pixelCount = data.length / 4;
        for (var i = 0; i < pixelCount; i++) {
            var gray = (data[i] * 0.3) + (data[i+1] * 0.59) + (data[i+2] * 0.11);
            data[i] = gray;
            data[i+1] = gray;
            data[i+2] = gray;
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }
</script>
```

But when I run the code in Safari and Firefox, this is what happens: [grayscale only partly affects image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcstS.png)

But, I noticed that if I change the canvas.height dimension in imageData to dimensions significantly larger than the canvas (such as 2000), then the entire image is grayscaled. The fry.jpg file only has dimensions of 387x315 on my computer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Each pixel is 4 items long, one each for red, green, blue and alpha. Remove the `/4` from `data.length / 4;`  and loop with `i+= 4` instead of `i++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only looping through 1/4 of the image when you divide the imageData.data array by 4.

Each pixel takes 4 values, one each for each channel red, green, blue, and alpha.

The quickest way to iterate them all is

```
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var data = imageData.data;
    var channelCount = data.length; // Total number of channel data
    var i = 0;  // counter
    var gray;   // computered Gray scale
    while(i < channelCount){  // while not done all
        gray = (data[i] * 0.3) + (data[i+1] * 0.59) + (data[i+2] * 0.11);
        data[i++] = data[i++] = data[i++] = gray; // assign pixel RGB
        i++;  // skip the alpha
    }
    // put it back onto the canvas.
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation and example are really helpful.